# We cannot install extension in admin panel in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento

We have installed magento 2.3 community edition in windows. We use Xampp 7.2.20. Magento installation is done successfully and admin panel is running fine. But when we try to install any extension from extension manager section it shows different errors. The errors is like as followings:

Step 1: Readiness Check

**Error! You need to resolve these issues to continue.**

Check Updater Application Availability

Updater application is available.

Check Cron Scripts

Cron script readiness check passed.

Check Component Dependency

Component dependency is correct.

PHP Settings Check *

Need Help? PHP Extension Help

PHP Extensions Check

missing PHP extensions. Hide detail

The best way to resolve this is to install the correct missing extensions. The exact fix depends on our server, your host, and other system variables.
 Our PHP extension help can get you started.

For additional assistance, contact your hosting provider.

```
    In some cases, you might have two PHP configuration files: one for the PHP command line and for the web server. If so, make the change in both php.ini files. For details, see the php.ini reference.
```

We cannot understand what is the problem in php extension and php settings. We cannot understand which extension, library, module is missing to install extension.

If any one has solution please give us.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following modules are installed and enabled on your server. This are the required PHP extension for Magento 2

bc-math

curl

gd, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both

intl

PDO/MySQL

SimpleXML

soap

xml

xsl

zipmbstring

mbstring

mcrypt

mhash

openssl